# configuration of log file

Tags: logs

For Solaris there is a file called /etc/default/su which tells where the sulog data is stored and the file name as well.. Like wise do we have any file on AIX, RHEL6 , RHEL 7 and HP-UX to identify in which location switch user logs are stored.

Solaris sample output below:

## ident  "@(#)su.dfl     1.6     93/08/14 SMI"   /* SVr4.0 1.2   */

## SULOG determines the location of the file used to log all su attempts

#
SULOG=/var/adm/sulog

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same `/var/adm/sulog` file on AIX and HP-UX. On RHEL, this info is located at -

`/var/log/secure`